# how to make an html list scrollable

Tags: html, css

I have this html list and it looks good. The problem with it that when the list becomes long then its missing a scroll for it and you cannot go down to see the rest of the list as its height becomes more than the page height! so I need to make it scrollable with y axes. html and css code is below

html

```
 <section class="demo">
                                    <dl class="list maki">
                                        <dt>Errors</dt>
            <dd><a href="#">    Name1   </a></dd>
            <dd><a href="#">    Name2   </a></dd>
            <dd><a href="#">    Name3   </a></dd>
            <dd><a href="#">    Name4   </a></dd>
            <dd><a href="#">    Name5   </a></dd>
            <dd><a href="#">    Name6   </a></dd>
 </dl>
    </section>
```

CSS

```
body:before {

    position: absolute;
    content: '';
    opacity: 0.8;
    height: 100%;
    width: 100%;
    left: 0;
    top: 0;
}

a {

    -webkit-transition: all 250ms cubic-bezier(0.230, 1.000, 0.320, 1.000);
    -moz-transition: all 250ms cubic-bezier(0.230, 1.000, 0.320, 1.000);
    -ms-transition: all 250ms cubic-bezier(0.230, 1.000, 0.320, 1.000);
    -o-transition: all 250ms cubic-bezier(0.230, 1.000, 0.320, 1.000);
    transition: all 250ms cubic-bezier(0.230, 1.000, 0.320, 1.000);

    text-decoration: none;
}

.header {

    text-align: center;
    position: absolute;
    z-index: 1;
    color: #333;
    width: 100%;
    top: 5%;
}

.header h1 {

    letter-spacing: -1px;
    text-shadow: -2px -1px 1px #fff, 1px 2px 2px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
    font-weight: 300;
    font-size: 36px;
    margin: 0;
}

.header h2 {

    text-transform: uppercase;
    text-shadow: -2px -1px 1px #fff, 1px 1px 1px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.15);
    font-weight: 300;
    font-size: 12px;
    color: rgba(0,0,0,0.7);
    margin: 0;
}

.demo:after {

    box-shadow: 0 1px 16px rgba(0,0,0,0.15);
    position: absolute;
    content: '';
    height: 10px;
    width: 100%;
    top: 0;
}

/* List styles */

.list {

    -webkit-transform-style: preserve-3d;
    -moz-transform-stle: preserve-3d;
    -ms-transform-style: preserve-3d;
    -o-transform-style: preserve-3d;
    transform-style: preserve-3d;
    
    text-transform: uppercase;
    position: absolute;
    margin-left: -140px;
    top: 20%;
}

.list a {
    
    display: block;
    color: #fff;
}

.list a:hover {
    text-indent: 20px;
}

.list dt, .list dd {

    text-indent: 10px;
    line-height: 55px;
    background: #E0FBAC;
    margin: 0;
    height: 55px;
    width: 270px;
    color: #fff;
}

.list dt {

    /* Since we're hiding elements behind here, we need it in 3d */
    -webkit-transform: translateZ(0.3px);
    -moz-transform: translateZ(0.3px);
    -ms-transform: translateZ(0.3px);
    -o-transform: translateZ(0.3px);
    transform: translateZ(0.3px);

    text-shadow: 1px 1px 2px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
    font-size: 15px;
}

.list dd {

    border-top: 1px dashed rgba(255,255,255,0.3);
    line-height: 35px;
    font-size: 11px;
    height: 35px;
    margin: 0;
}

/* UI */

.toggle {
  
    -webkit-transform: translateZ(100px);
    -moz-transform: translateZ(100px);
    -ms-transform: translateZ(100px);
    -o-transform: translateZ(100px);
    transform: translateZ(100px);

    box-shadow: 0 1px 4px rgba(0,0,0,0.15);
    border-radius: 3px;

    text-transform: uppercase;
    letter-spacing: -1px;
    line-height: 50px;
    margin-left: -70px;
    margin-top: -20px;
    background: #2b2b2b;
    text-align: center;
    font-size: 12px;
    position: absolute;
    z-index: 1;
    height: 50px;
    bottom: 10%;
    width: 140px;
    color: #fff;
    left: 50%;
}

.toggle:hover {
    
    background: #E42692;
}

/* No CSS 3D support warning */
.warning {

    -webkit-transform: translateZ(2px);
    -moz-transform: translateZ(2px);
    -ms-transform: translateZ(2px);
    -o-transform: translateZ(2px);
    transform: translateZ(2px);

    background: rgba(255,255,255,0.6);
    position: fixed;
    display: none;
    z-index: 999;
    height: 100%;
    width: 100%;
    left: 0;
    top: 0;
}

.warning .message {

    box-shadow: 0 1px 8px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.6);
    border-radius: 5px;
    text-align: center;
    margin-left: -150px;
    margin-top: -60px;
    line-height: 1.5;
    background: #222;
    font-size: 12px;
    position: absolute;
    padding: 10px;
    width: 280px;
    color: #fff;
    left: 50%;
    top: 50%;
}

.warning .message h1 {

    font-weight: 300;
    font-size: 14px;
}

.warning .message a {

    text-decoration: none;
    color: #73C8A9;
}

/* Individual styles */

.sashimi dt, .sashimi dd, .sashimi a { background: #73C8A9; }
.nigiri dt, .nigiri dd, .nigiri a { background: #DC143C; }
.maki dt, .maki dd, .maki a { background: #DC143C; }

.sashimi a:hover { background: #61c19e; }
.nigiri a:hover { background: #d31b46; }
.maki a:hover { background: linear-gradient(#072648, #053b75);}

.nigiri {

    -webkit-transform: perspective(1200px) rotateY(40deg) !important;
    -moz-transform: perspective(1200px) rotateY(40deg) !important;
    -ms-transform: perspective(1200px) rotateY(40deg) !important;
    -o-transform: perspective(1200px) rotateY(40deg) !important;
    transform: perspective(1200px) rotateY(40deg) !important;

    -webkit-transform-origin: 110% 25%;
    -moz-transform-origin: 110% 25%;
    -ms-transform-origin: 110% 25%;
    -o-transform-origin: 110% 25%;
    transform-origin: 110% 25%;

    left: 20%;
}

.maki {

    -webkit-transform: perspective(600px) translateZ(1px) !important;
    -moz-transform: perspective(600px) translateZ(1px) !important;
    -ms-transform: perspective(600px) translateZ(1px) !important;
    -o-transform: perspective(600px) translateZ(1px) !important;
    transform: perspective(600px) translateZ(1px) !important;

    left: 50%;
}

.sashimi {

    -webkit-transform: perspective(1200px) rotateY(-40deg) !important;
    -moz-transform: perspective(1200px) rotateY(-40deg) !important;
    -ms-transform: perspective(1200px) rotateY(-40deg) !important;
    -o-transform: perspective(1200px) rotateY(-40deg) !important;
    transform: perspective(1200px) rotateY(-40deg) !important;

    -webkit-transform-origin: -10% 25%;
    -moz-transform-origin: -10% 25%;
    -ms-transform-origin: -10% 25%;
    -o-transform-origin: -10% 25%;
    transform-origin: -10% 25%;

    left: 80%;
}
```

Comment: Have you tried using "overflow-y:scroll;" on your <dl> element with a max height? For example, <style> ... dl { overflow-y:scroll;max-height:200px; } ... </style>

Answer (score 2):

You should wrap the entire `dd` tag to one parent and they give try giving styling of `overflow` with some specified height.

```css
body:before {

    position: absolute;
    content: '';
    opacity: 0.8;
    height: 100%;
    width: 100%;
    left: 0;
    top: 0;
}

a {

    -webkit-transition: all 250ms cubic-bezier(0.230, 1.000, 0.320, 1.000);
    -moz-transition: all 250ms cubic-bezier(0.230, 1.000, 0.320, 1.000);
    -ms-transition: all 250ms cubic-bezier(0.230, 1.000, 0.320, 1.000);
    -o-transition: all 250ms cubic-bezier(0.230, 1.000, 0.320, 1.000);
    transition: all 250ms cubic-bezier(0.230, 1.000, 0.320, 1.000);

    text-decoration: none;
}

.header {

    text-align: center;
    position: absolute;
    z-index: 1;
    color: #333;
    width: 100%;
    top: 5%;
}

.header h1 {

    letter-spacing: -1px;
    text-shadow: -2px -1px 1px #fff, 1px 2px 2px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
    font-weight: 300;
    font-size: 36px;
    margin: 0;
}

.header h2 {

    text-transform: uppercase;
    text-shadow: -2px -1px 1px #fff, 1px 1px 1px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.15);
    font-weight: 300;
    font-size: 12px;
    color: rgba(0,0,0,0.7);
    margin: 0;
}

.demo:after {

    box-shadow: 0 1px 16px rgba(0,0,0,0.15);
    position: absolute;
    content: '';
    height: 10px;
    width: 100%;
    top: 0;
}

/* List styles */

.list {

    -webkit-transform-style: preserve-3d;
    -moz-transform-stle: preserve-3d;
    -ms-transform-style: preserve-3d;
    -o-transform-style: preserve-3d;
    transform-style: preserve-3d;
    
    text-transform: uppercase;
    position: absolute;
    margin-left: -140px;
    top: 20%;
}

.list a {
    
    display: block;
    color: #fff;
}
.lists__error{ 
  overflow-y:scroll;
  height:200px;
}

.list a:hover {
    text-indent: 20px;
}

.list dt, .list dd {

    text-indent: 10px;
    line-height: 55px;
    background: #E0FBAC;
    margin: 0;
    height: 55px;
    width: 270px;
    color: #fff;
}

.list dt {

    /* Since we're hiding elements behind here, we need it in 3d */
    -webkit-transform: translateZ(0.3px);
    -moz-transform: translateZ(0.3px);
    -ms-transform: translateZ(0.3px);
    -o-transform: translateZ(0.3px);
    transform: translateZ(0.3px);

    text-shadow: 1px 1px 2px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
    font-size: 15px;
}

.list dd {

    border-top: 1px dashed rgba(255,255,255,0.3);
    line-height: 35px;
    font-size: 11px;
    height: 35px;
    margin: 0;
}

/* UI */

.toggle {
  
    -webkit-transform: translateZ(100px);
    -moz-transform: translateZ(100px);
    -ms-transform: translateZ(100px);
    -o-transform: translateZ(100px);
    transform: translateZ(100px);

    box-shadow: 0 1px 4px rgba(0,0,0,0.15);
    border-radius: 3px;

    text-transform: uppercase;
    letter-spacing: -1px;
    line-height: 50px;
    margin-left: -70px;
    margin-top: -20px;
    background: #2b2b2b;
    text-align: center;
    font-size: 12px;
    position: absolute;
    z-index: 1;
    height: 50px;
    bottom: 10%;
    width: 140px;
    color: #fff;
    left: 50%;
}

.toggle:hover {
    
    background: #E42692;
}

/* No CSS 3D support warning */
.warning {

    -webkit-transform: translateZ(2px);
    -moz-transform: translateZ(2px);
    -ms-transform: translateZ(2px);
    -o-transform: translateZ(2px);
    transform: translateZ(2px);

    background: rgba(255,255,255,0.6);
    position: fixed;
    display: none;
    z-index: 999;
    height: 100%;
    width: 100%;
    left: 0;
    top: 0;
}

.warning .message {

    box-shadow: 0 1px 8px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.6);
    border-radius: 5px;
    text-align: center;
    margin-left: -150px;
    margin-top: -60px;
    line-height: 1.5;
    background: #222;
    font-size: 12px;
    position: absolute;
    padding: 10px;
    width: 280px;
    color: #fff;
    left: 50%;
    top: 50%;
}

.warning .message h1 {

    font-weight: 300;
    font-size: 14px;
}

.warning .message a {

    text-decoration: none;
    color: #73C8A9;
}

/* Individual styles */

.sashimi dt, .sashimi dd, .sashimi a { background: #73C8A9; }
.nigiri dt, .nigiri dd, .nigiri a { background: #DC143C; }
.maki dt, .maki dd, .maki a { background: #DC143C; }

.sashimi a:hover { background: #61c19e; }
.nigiri a:hover { background: #d31b46; }
.maki a:hover { background: linear-gradient(#072648, #053b75);}

.nigiri {

    -webkit-transform: perspective(1200px) rotateY(40deg) !important;
    -moz-transform: perspective(1200px) rotateY(40deg) !important;
    -ms-transform: perspective(1200px) rotateY(40deg) !important;
    -o-transform: perspective(1200px) rotateY(40deg) !important;
    transform: perspective(1200px) rotateY(40deg) !important;

    -webkit-transform-origin: 110% 25%;
    -moz-transform-origin: 110% 25%;
    -ms-transform-origin: 110% 25%;
    -o-transform-origin: 110% 25%;
    transform-origin: 110% 25%;

    left: 20%;
}

.maki {

    -webkit-transform: perspective(600px) translateZ(1px) !important;
    -moz-transform: perspective(600px) translateZ(1px) !important;
    -ms-transform: perspective(600px) translateZ(1px) !important;
    -o-transform: perspective(600px) translateZ(1px) !important;
    transform: perspective(600px) translateZ(1px) !important;

    left: 50%;
}

.sashimi {

    -webkit-transform: perspective(1200px) rotateY(-40deg) !important;
    -moz-transform: perspective(1200px) rotateY(-40deg) !important;
    -ms-transform: perspective(1200px) rotateY(-40deg) !important;
    -o-transform: perspective(1200px) rotateY(-40deg) !important;
    transform: perspective(1200px) rotateY(-40deg) !important;

    -webkit-transform-origin: -10% 25%;
    -moz-transform-origin: -10% 25%;
    -ms-transform-origin: -10% 25%;
    -o-transform-origin: -10% 25%;
    transform-origin: -10% 25%;

    left: 80%;
}
```

```html
<html>
<body>
<section class="demo">
<dl class="list maki">
<dt>Errors</dt>
            <div class="lists__error">
            <dd><a href="#">    Name1   </a></dd>
            <dd><a href="#">    Name2   </a></dd>
            <dd><a href="#">    Name3   </a></dd>
            <dd><a href="#">    Name4   </a></dd>
            <dd><a href="#">    Name5   </a></dd>
            <dd><a href="#">    Name6   </a></dd>
            <dd><a href="#">    Name7   </a></dd>
            <dd><a href="#">    Name8   </a></dd>
            <dd><a href="#">    Name9   </a></dd>
            <dd><a href="#">    Name10   </a></dd>
            </div>
 </dl>
    </section>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

you can use `overflow-y: scroll;`

example code :

```css
dl{
  overflow-y: scroll;
}
```

by the way all your css codes there are not necessary for the question

Answer (score 0):

Make parent class relative and make absolute class=list__maki, then use overflow-x:hidden; overflow-y:scroll;

Suggestion:Also you may add effects like hover to look lists items effective.

Thanks.